# Radio button returns value of "on" in PhoneGap Build app

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I have tried JQuery and plain Javascript in every imaginable way to try to get the value of a checked radio button within a PhoneGap Build app.

In the app on both Android and iOS the value comes back as "on" consistently.

The real value *does* return correctly in any browser via a webpage on desktop and mobile.

**Sample input code:**
`<input type="radio" id="inpt1_1" name="CheckBtn" value="testValue" />`

**Sample jQuery code:**
`var selectedValue = $("input[name='CheckBtn']:checked").val();`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Radiobuttons and checkboxes allways return value = on if no value attribute is present.

In the example below you can see it. Maybe your jQuery selector is not correct (maybe there is another radiobutton with this name or something like this)

```js
$(":radio").click(function () {
   $("span").text($(":radio:checked").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="inpt1_1">
    <input type="radio" id="inpt1_1" name="CheckBtn" value="testValue" /> with value
</label><br>
<label for="inpt1_2">
    <input type="radio" id="inpt1_2" name="CheckBtn" /> without value
</label><br>
the value is: <span></span>
```